# vmware-installer -u vmware

Tags: virtualbox, vmware

I have 2 vmware products expired and tried to remove them. Non of them works, because the uninstaller could not detect the installed product (Player or Workstation). How can manually remove them?

```
 vmware-installer -u vmware-player
```

### VMware® Workstation 14 Pro, 14.1.7 build-12989993

### VMware® Workstation 14 Player, 14.1.7 build-12989993

Comment: what  is the output of vmware-installer -l

Comment: the output was sort of something that the player was not installed on my system and pointed out the other software I have installed, ex Horizon. Anyhow I solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the removal instructions on the vmware website don't work, (they didn't work for me) then remove all the files manually. One way is to open the file explorer with `sudo nautilus` and then do a normal search for vmware, then delete the folders/files.